# Align equations with align

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, vertical-alignment

I want to align the following equation over multiple lines:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\tilde{E}^{n+1} \left( \Sigma X \right) 
&= \left[ \Sigma^{\infty}  \Sigma X, \Sigma^{n+1} E \right]
 &\stackrel{Adjointness}{\cong} \left[ \Sigma^{-1} \Sigma \Sigma^{\infty} X, \Sigma^n E \right] \\
&\cong \left[ \Sigma^{\infty} X, \Sigma^n E \right] 
 &\cong \tilde{E}^n(X).
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

but it gives the following output:

[image]

How can I align the Isomorphism sign in the lower right to the one in the upper right?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two renderings (I'd prefer the second one, avoiding the unsightly blank space).

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand{\commentedrel}[2]{% #1 = relation, #2 = comment
  \overset{\substack{\text{\makebox[0pt]{#2}}\\\downarrow}}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \tilde{E}^{n+1} ( \Sigma X ) 
&=
  [ \Sigma^{\infty}  \Sigma X, \Sigma^{n+1} E ]
&& \commentedrel{\cong}{Adjointness}
  [ \Sigma^{-1} \Sigma \Sigma^{\infty} X, \Sigma^n E ] \\
&\cong
  [ \Sigma^{\infty} X, \Sigma^n E ] 
&&\cong
  \tilde{E}^n(X).
\end{alignat*}

\begin{align*}
  \tilde{E}^{n+1} ( \Sigma X ) 
&=
  [ \Sigma^{\infty}  \Sigma X, \Sigma^{n+1} E ]
  \commentedrel{\cong}{Adjointness}
  [ \Sigma^{-1} \Sigma \Sigma^{\infty} X, \Sigma^n E ] \\
&\cong
  [ \Sigma^{\infty} X, \Sigma^n E ] 
  \cong
  \tilde{E}^n(X).
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Note no `\left` and `\right` and `\overset` instead of `\stackrel`, but hidden in a command for ease of input and better readability.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

[image]

Do note that none of the `\left` and `\right` sizing directives in your code do anything useful. Get rid of them.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathclap' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\tilde{E}^{n+1} ( \Sigma X ) 
  &= [\Sigma^{\infty} \Sigma X, \Sigma^{n+1} E ]
  &&\stackrel{\substack{\mathclap{\text{Adjointness}}\\ \downarrow}}{\cong} 
  [\Sigma^{-1} \Sigma \Sigma^{\infty} X, \Sigma^n E ] \\
& \cong [\Sigma^{\infty} X, \Sigma^n E ] 
  &&\cong \tilde{E}^n(X).
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do the brackets $[$ and $]$ do?

Comment: @Candyblock — I just copied your code. You must be in a far better position to assess what the square brackets signify.